# How to swap MEMSQL tables using an atomic operation

Tags: mysql, singlestore

I have 2 column store **MEMSQL** tables a_primary and a_seconday. The a_primary is responsible to serve all read requests. I perform data refresh from warehouse to a_secondary table. Once data load and analyze is completed I want to make a_secondary to primary table. I have tried [hotswap tables in mysql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22108/how-do-i-swap-tables-in-mysql) option but that didn't work.

Other options are like create view on top of primary table and alter it once load is completed to point to secondary table.

Any suggestions how to optimally swap 2 **memsql** tables using an atomic operation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could use views for this purpose. You can atomically change the view from one table to the other with ALTER VIEW. This sounds like it would be a good option for your use case, as you only need to atomically swap read requests, which can reference the view, while the write requests directly reference the underlying base tables.

Unfortunately it is not currently possible to atomically swap table names in MemSQL. You can swap table names with multiple separate ALTER TABLE RENAME commands: B->C, A->B and C->A. But it's not atomic and there is a gap in visibility of the table during this process.